# Equivalent for “Jinx!”

Tags: expressions, jeux

When two people say the same thing at the same time what do people say in France? In English it’s “Jinx!”

Answer (score 7):

My kids and their friends say:

> [Chips](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chips) !

then, if that was simultaneous again:

> Double chips !
>   ...
>   Triple chips !

and so on until one wins.

When more than two people say the same thing at the same time, one might also say:

> Chips personnel !

to win the "contest".

The loser has to stay mute until his/her first name is pronounced by anyone.

Here is a reference: https://warriors-en-savates.skyrock.com/1309936278-La-Loi-du-Chips.html

A "micro-poll" shows that this expression is known by young people between 11 and 20 years old in both Paris area and Brittany but mostly unknown by older people.

Comment: C'est \tʃɪps\ ou  \ʃips\, je veux dire le début du mot, et on prononce le s à la fin ?

Comment: I am 26 in east of France, and we still say Chips. Sometimes it lets me have a quiet evening with my boyfriend not allowed to talk :)

Comment: @suiiurisesse That's the same word as the French one for "crisps". The final \s\ is always pronounced. A leading \t\ is generally not, but might be heard in *double chips* to ease pronunciation.

Comment: @jlliagre Haha, j'ai du regarder au dictionnaire pour _crisps_ que je ne connais pas, contrairement à l'adjectif _crispy_ etc.

Answer (score 4):

In my extended family, we say

> Les grands esprits se rencontrent

(I've never heard of "chips" in the other responses.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is an "official" word for this situation.

But, your question reminds  me, when i was a child, we used to say "Chips" simultaneously.

So, if our "Chips" was originally a distortion of your "Jinx"... This is very funny.

Comment: Where are you located? Never heard of that myself...

Comment: Never used it myself, but my sons (teenagers,  in Belgium) use it indeed as well.

Comment: Mes enfants utilisaient le terme "chips" lorsqu'ils étaient scolarisés dans le Sud Ouest de la France. Leurs cousins qui habitent dans l'Est de la France ne connaissaient pas cette expression.